# SQL Error - You tried to execute a query that ...

Tags: sql

I have a query like this. When executing it I am getting this error.

```
            System.Text.StringBuilder qry = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            qry.Append(" SELECT OfferC.TypeIE, OfferC.RegNo ");
            qry.Append(" FROM OfferC ");
            qry.Append(" WHERE OfferC.RegNo IN (");
            qry.Append(string.Join(",",m_SelectableOrganizations.ConvertAll(IntToString).ToArray())).Append(")");
            qry.Append(" GROUP BY OfferC.RegNo, OfferC.TypeIE");
            qry.Append(" ORDER BY OfferC.Rating;");
```

**You Tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expressions 'OfferC.Rating' as part ot an aggregate function.**

I tried to do something like this.

```
SELECT ...

FROM ...

WHERE ...

GROUP BY ... 

ORDER BY ...
```

But still getting the same error. And a screenshot to error.
[image]

Thanks for help.

Comment: You need to include OfferC.Rating in Group By clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include `OfferC.Rating` in `GROUP BY` clause, otherwise `ORDER BY OfferC.Rating` can't happen since it's been grouped with other criteria and not by `OfferC.Rating`